# scope variable not working with ng-include src

Tags: angularjs

So first of all, this works: (The html loads)

```
<div ng-include src="'start.html'"></div>
```

Here, the sideBar variable shows that the sideBar scope variable is equal to 'start.html' but when I insert it into the ng-include src - it does not work.

```
<div>{{ sideBar }}</div> <!-- sideBar appears on the page as start.html -->
<div ng-include src="'{{ sideBar }}'"></div>
```

This also does not work:

```
<div ng-include src="{{ sideBar }}"></div>
```

and this does not work either:

```
<div ng-include src={{ sideBar }}></div>
```

only this works:

```
<div ng-include src="'start.html'"></div>
```

How can I make the include work with a scope variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) for `ng-include`.

Following works:

```
<div ng-include="sideBar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-model="sideBar" ng-include src="sideBar"></div>
```

this works